# PowerBI DAX measure - Filter rows where column has to have a specific value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure like below

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Value]); FILTER(ALL(Sales); Sales[Month] IN {"01"; "02"}))
```

When filtering on a slicer e.g. `Department` The Sales value is not changing, it's always stuck at 3500. Is there a way to filter through the rows even if the Sales[Month] Column can only be `01 02`

Below is a one-to-many relationship of two tables.

Employees

```
Employee(Unique) Department
Cosmo               A1
Kramer              A1
Kessler             B1
```

Sales

```
Employee   Month    Value
Kramer      01      2500
Kramer      03      5000
Kessler     01      500
Cosmo       02      500
```

Using the measure gives me row 1,3 and 4 and returns a value of 3500. If I pick department B1 I would like it to return row 3 (500) and A1 row 1 and 4 (3000).

Is there some way to make this happen? I can not use the "Edit interactions" in format, since this measure is to be used in a visual that uses other measures. I would like the measure to be responsible alone for this interaction.

Edit: If I only check month `03` in my slicer, the measure should still show values for month `01` and `02` and keep adjusting to department slicer.

Edit2: I have some pictures of my problem below:

Relationships

[image]

image of below shows Value and 1&2_Target are both 500. Whereas only Value should show 500 and 1&2_Target should be 3000. I'd like the graph to simply ignore the date slicer by the dax formula.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that your `ALL(Sales)` part is stripping off the department filter context from the slicer.

There are a variety of ways to fix this. You could probably use `ALLSELECTED` or `ALLEXCEPT` inside your `FILTER()` to get what you want, but you can also simply do this:

```
= CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Value]); Sales[Month] IN {"01"; "02"})
```

In this case, you are just replacing the `[Month]` filter context with what you want it to be and not touching the filter context for `[Department]`.

---

**Edit:** If the above doesn't work, try resetting the `Sales[Month]` filter context and then applying the specific filter as follows:

```
= CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Value]); ALL(Sales[Month]); Sales[Month] IN {"01"; "02"})
```

If you have months in your slicer, those get passed to the filter context. The `ALL()` function clears the filter context for `[Month]` and then you apply the particular ones you want.

---

**Edit 2:** I see that you have a `Date` table. Please try replacing

```
1&2_Target = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Value]), ALL(Sales[Date]), Sales[Date] IN {"1", "2"})
```

with this

```
1&2_Target = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Value]), ALL('Date'[Date]), Sales[Date] IN {"1", "2"})
```

Comment: The simple way does not work unfortunately. It allows me to filter departments, but if I uncheck month 01 and 02 in my slicer it will change the values, which it should not. 

I'm not sure how to work with the ALLSELECTED or ALLEXCEPT, they pretty much return the same things. But it's probably my use of them that is incorrect.

Comment: @vandelay I didn't know you had a slicer with months. Please see my edit.

Comment: @vandelay Do you have a stripped down .pibix file you can share? It's difficult to know what's going on when I can't see all the context.

Comment: I don't have one at my place right now. But I can try and create one, but can't do it tonight tho.

Comment: I've updated with a simple image, hope that helps. Thanks tho.

Comment: @vandelay Ah, I see now. I didn't know you had a `Date` table. Try changing `ALL(Sales[Date])` to `ALL('Date'[Date])` in your `1&2_Target` measure.

Comment: ah didn't realize that might be relevant! It works perfectly now, thanks alot for your time :) I gave you the bounty aswell. Have a great day!